# Windows Phone textbox limits to only accepts 8 characters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, hex

I'm having a problem with a Windows Phone 7 application that I'm coding (Using Visual Studio 2010). My code looks like this:

```
private void Key1Input_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string hexOnly= Key1Input.Text;
  int n = 0;
  if (!int.TryParse(hexOnly, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out n) &&
    hexOnly!= String.Empty)
  {
    Key1Input.Text = hexOnly.Remove(hexOnly.Length - 1, 1);
    Key1Input.SelectionStart = Key1Input.Text.Length;
  }
}
```

which is a same code that can also be found from this web site: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ec7b777d-deb1-45e1-b66e-e25daddf6497/text-box-which-accepts-only-hexadecimal-values

The code works fine, but when I tried to insert 9th character to the textbox, it didn't show up. My textbox's Maxlength value is 12. After inserting some breakpoints to the code and debugging the app, I noticed it goes inside the if statement when there's 8 hex numbers and trying to type more. Am I doing something wrong, or are there some kinds of limitations with WP7.

I also tried the other 2 codes from the same site. The second one works, while the third one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest 8-digit hex number is `F0000000`, which is greater than `Int32.MaxValue`. Try `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: Was literally just typing this. Good to know I figured out the correct issue.

Comment: @GabrielNegut you're right, I haven't been using `long` for 2-3 years, so had already forgot one can replace `int` with it. Thank you.